# Sticky td with rowspan moves out of table boundaries on scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with sticky header and sticky tds which have rowspan.
When it's scrolled td with rowspan appears on top of it's header (according to this example it is the first column).
Specifying z-index puts header on top of the td but overlaps its text.
How can I prevent this?
My first version was without rowspan, contained empty cells and behaved correctly.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
}
*/

table {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  /* z-index: 100; */
}

thead th {
  border: 0.1rem solid #ddd;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

tbody td[rowspan] {
  border-top: 0.1rem solid #999;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1.4rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* z-index: 10; */
}
```

```html
<!-- <div class="wrapper"> -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="10">cell_text_1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="10">cell_text_2</td>
      <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="18">cell_text_3</td>
      <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="7">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="12">cell_text_4</td>
      <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
      <td>cell_text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: is it first column going out of table right

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Any row with colspan must stick under the header. At one point while scrolling some of the rows with rowspan overlap the header. According to this example first column does.

Comment: wrong rowspan given to tr

Comment: Which one? It is correct by me. The table is generated.

Comment: check below answer

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

try below, rowspan mistake

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
}
*/

table {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}

thead th {
  border: 0.1rem solid #ddd;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

tbody td[rowspan] {
  border-top: 0.1rem solid #999;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1.4rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* z-index: 10; */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">cell_text_1</td>
        <td rowspan="4">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">cell_text_2</td>
        <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="18">cell_text_3</td>
        <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="7">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="12">cell_text_4</td>
        <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan="14">cell_text_5</td>
        <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">cell_text</td>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
        <td>cell_text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: No, Mayur. You removed position sticky of the rows with rowspan but like I said those must stick under the header while scrolling, thus must be sticky. It is not a mistake.

Comment: do you want to sticky 1 row also with header

Comment: Not the first row. I've already implemented the stickiness. It must be the same. Run my snippet, I've made some changes. Scroll it slowly to the bottom. cell_text_3 will overlap col1 eventually. This is my only problem.

Comment: @noneedname  , now check again , i made changes, it's worked

Comment: MAYUR SANCHETI, so you think trimming the table is the way to solve my problem? Have you made any changes in CSS?

Comment: no css change, only changes table rowspan. try this code

Comment: Not the rowspan, you are modifying table data, you can't do this. It is not a solution.

Comment: i am not modifying table data, you can add remaining table data into this .

Comment: You are incorrectly modifying rowspans and trimming table data. This is just an example to demonstrate the problem. But like I said this table is generated, it is not static. Data is selected from the database and rowspans are calculated. It can be different. Long, short, wide... You can't modify html.

Comment: colspan 3 overlap header only because of rowspan, is it possible to change in rowspan calculation

Comment: now i made some changes in css , you can put any value of rowspan, now it's not depend on rowspan. check it.

Comment: Now we are right back where we started. I already tried trick with z-index. It just puts header on top. But td with cell_text_3 must stick under the header. It must be visible till next row won't overlap it. Like it's done with cell_text_1 and cell_text_2.

Comment: now check again

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Putting the text of the `td` with `rowspan` in `div` or `span` element gives the proper results.
But I still don't understand why...